# Насколько законно брать платные данные сайта через его код?

Tags: юридические-аспекты

Мне понадобился *SVG* код одной иконки. Я нашел её, но сайт не позволяет скопировать код бесплатно. Насколько законно с моей стороны будет зайти в код сайта и там найти *SVG*?

Сам сайт: https://icons8.com/pricing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Любые вопросы насчет законности или незаконности применения какого-то контента прописаны в лицензионном соглашении.

В большинстве юрисдикций также установлено, что:

- авторские права возникают непосредственно в момент создания произведения
- они автоматически защищают от любого использования произведения без письменного разрешения автора

Таким образом, даже если лицензия на сайте не опубликована, вы все равно ничего не можете делать с контентом без получения письменного разрешения автора.